# Exact Change Function with Multiple Function Outputs

Tags: python, function

I am trying to program a function that calculates exact changes when an amount is given, and prints out 'no change' when the input is 0. Utilizing unpacking, I have tried to make the code work, but it seems I have met my knowledge barrier.

If I were to input 145, my desired output is:

```
1 dollar 1 quarter 2 dimes
```

As you can see, nickels and pennies are not in the output because their value were 0.

Below is my attempt(Making it plural can be done, but I have not done so in this code for the time being):

```
def exact_change(user_total):
    if user_total <= 0:
        return print('no change')
    elif user_total > 0:
        num_dollars = user_total//100
        user_total = user_total%100
        num_quarters = user_total//25
        user_total = user_total%25
        num_dimes = user_total//10
        user_total = user_total%10
        num_nickels = user_total//5
        user_total = user_total%5
        num_pennies = user_total//1
        return num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    input_val = int(input())    
    num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies = exact_change(input_val)

    print(num_dollars)
    print(num_quarters)
    print(num_dimes)
    print(num_nickels)
    print(num_pennies)
```

If input == 145, output comes out to be

```
1
1
2
0
0
```

Comment: What part(s) do you need help with: suppressing printing of 0's, printing the coin names, and/or putting them all on the same line?  What have you tried to address *any* of these?

Comment: A few `if` statements and reading `print` documentation will help

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to print the zeroes at the end, you can try:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_val = int(input())
    for value in exact_change(input_val):
        if value > 0:
            print(value)
```

So that it only prints values > 0

Answer (score 0):

For those coming after me I think this is what you are wanting.

```
num_dollars = user_total//100
user_total = user_total%100
if num_dollars == 1:
    print(num_dollars, 'dollar')
if num_dollars >= 2:
    print(num_dollars, 'dollars')
```

You need to put the print statements inside the function, so that all you have to do is call the function you need.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still needs this, it worked for me.

```
def exact_change(user_total):
    num_dollars=0
    num_quarters=0
    num_dimes=0
    num_nickels=0
    num_pennies=0
    num_dollars = user_total // 100
    user_total = user_total % 100
    num_quarters = user_total // 25
    user_total = user_total % 25
    num_dimes = user_total // 10
    user_total = user_total % 10
    num_nickels = user_total // 5
    num_pennies = user_total % 5
    return num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    input_val = int(input())    
    num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies = exact_change(input_val)
    if num_dollars == 0 and num_quarters == 0 and num_dimes == 0 and num_nickels == 0 and num_pennies == 0:
        print('no change')
    if num_dollars == 1:
        print(num_dollars,'dollar')
    elif num_dollars > 1:
        print(num_dollars,'dollars')
    if num_quarters == 1:
        print(num_quarters,'quarter')
    elif num_quarters > 1:
        print(num_quarters,'quarters')
    if num_dimes == 1:
        print(num_dimes,'dime')
    elif num_dimes > 1:
        print(num_dimes,'dimes')
    if num_nickels == 1:
        print(num_nickels,'nickel')
    elif num_nickels > 1:
        print(num_nickels,'nickels')
    if num_pennies == 1:
        print(num_pennies,'penny')
    elif num_pennies > 1:
        print(num_pennies,'pennies')
```

Comment: Can you please update your answer with some code explanation? It will help others understand.